# Function is returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I've looked at some other SO answers, but can't seem to figure out how to fix this. When I console.log `this.checkIfEmailExists(form)` I get `[object Object]` instead of the boolean I am expecting

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { User } from '../shared/user.model';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './user.component.css'
  ]
  // providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  god = 'me, I am god';

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('User Component Appears!');
  }

  async onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    // Logs as '[object Object] please be a boooooolean'
    console.log(this.checkIfEmailExists(form) + ' please be a boooooolean');
  }

  checkIfEmailExists(form) {
    const emailToCheck = form.value.email;
    return this.userService.sendEmailToCheck(emailToCheck).subscribe(res => {
      // Logs as 'false <- keeping this here to...'
      console.log(
        res +
          ' <- keeping this here to make sure I dont break it, but delete at some point'
      );
      return res;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `checkIfEmailExists()` returns an object, not a boolean. It looks like you are returning a promise that needs to be resolved. What do you want to happen here? Are you sending an email to the user that contains instructions how to verify? If so, you certainly shouldn't wait for any kind of response. Instead, you need a link in the email and the rest of the processing happens when the user clicks that link.

Comment: Why when I console log `res` in `checkIfEmailExists()` does it log as a boolean (false in this case)? This code asks my backend if an email exists

Comment: Because `res` is in a callback function that you pass to `subscribe()`. That anonymous function is not called until some time after `checkIfEmailExists()` returns. I suggest that you add more `console.log()` statements to show where execution occurs in your code. For example, add a log at the start of `checkIfEmailExists()` and ones before and after you call it from `onSubmit()`.

Comment: If `sendEmailToCheck` returns an Angular [observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables), the function passed as an argument to `subscribe` is only called _after_ the email is sent, with an argument passed to it by the observable (that's the booean you're seeing). But `checkIfEmailExists` does not wait for anything; it returns the subscription object right away, which is the other thing you're seeing printed.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ah, I added those console.logs and it looks like the one I added in `onSubmit()` at the end after `checkIfEmailExists()` is called is logged before the ones inside `this.userService.sendEmailToCheck(emailToCheck).subscribe` are so it must be an asycronous issue

Comment: @RyanSoderberg Note that my answer is based on some assumptions about what `subscribe()` returns. These assumptions may be incorrect. jirassimok describes an alternative assumption in the comment above. To be sure, we would need more information about `UserService`, specifically the `sendEmailToCheck()` method.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, I've uploaded some of the code here https://repl.it/repls/BlueHelpfulCommands if this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `UserService.subscribe()` is asynchronous. I assume that it calls a promise. To log the result of that promise, you need to resolve it. One possibility is like this:

```
this.checkIfEmailExists(form).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Alternatively, you can use `async` and `await`. First, you need to declare `checkIfEmailExists()` as `async`:

```
async checkIfEmailExists(form) {
   // ...
}
```

Then you can `await` when you call it:

```
var res = await this.checkIfEmailExists(form);
console.log(res);
```

I suggest that you learn about promises in JavaScript and about `async` and `await` keywords.

Comment: Isn't that what the .subscribe is for? Resolving it?

Comment: I've tried adding await before `this.checkIfEmailExists(form)` but my code editor says `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)`

Comment: "Isn't that what the .subscribe is for? Resolving it?" No, subscribe just takes a callback function which will eventually be called when the promise resolves.

Comment: @RyanSoderberg You get that error because `checkIfEmailExists()` is not declared as `async`. See my edit for details.

Comment: Both functions are async now, but the message persists

Comment: @RyanSoderberg Then my suggested solution is probably incorrect. Check out the link that jirassimok gave for Angular observables to figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: @RyanSoderberg Also, it looks like you are using TypeScript instead of JavaScript. You should google the error message to find other suggestions how to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

`checkIfEmailExists` is returning the subscription of `checkIfEmailExists`.

In `console.log` this will be typecast to its type, which is why your seeing `[object object]`.

Convert `checkIfEmailExists` to a async function (probably doing something like `.toPromise()` on the `sendEmail()` method).